# How to control what of dependencies will be bundled into uber jar generated by Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

My project inherits default configuration from `spring-boot-starter-parent` . The command `mvn package` generates so-called uber Jar, which contains all the application compiled code plus all the dependencies from the dependency tree.

The problem is that there are too many dependencies copied into the target Jar file. I tried to control that by setting some of dependencies' scope to `compile`, but that didn't work.

Is it possible to control what dependencies will be taken into the final Jar file?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to exclude these if you are relying on them in a module that is building an application? Usually, the pattern is to build your app from a set of X modules and then bundle those in a module who is packaging "everything". That particular module should not define anything that you don't want in your app. Can you explain a bit more why you have to exclude them?

Comment: @snicoll, because this dependencies are only needed during compilation, they aren't used in a runtime.

Comment: I'd like to see a detailed list of what you have in your ueberjar and what you prefer not to have. Then we can have a more informed discussion  about what is "problematic" and what isn't.

Comment: @DaveSyer nothing is problematic, I just want to prevent from some of transitive dependencies to appear in the target jar file, so I've asked if that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

The ueberjar only contains the dependencies that you specifically asked for. I'm not sure what else you are looking for. If you are using "starter" poms as dependencies (no-one forces you to do that) then you are perhaps selecting more than you will strictly need at runtime. We do try to be conservative about the transitive of the starters, but the whole point of them is that they *have* transitive dependencies that might be useful. Like I said, you don't have to use them if you don't like them.

Comment: So, if I stay with starter pom there's no way to filter out some of dependencies?

Comment: Only the normal Maven/Gradle ways of filtering dependencies. They don't give you enough flexibility?

Comment: Do you know to do that with spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Comment: I believe the Boot plugin offers no features in this regard. You just use standard Maven features (like `<excludes>` or `<optional>true</optional>` in a `<dependency>` declaration). Or maybe I didn't understand the question?